# Azure SQL Data warehouse - Error while enabling statistics

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-sql-server

I am getting below error while enabling stats on Azure Sql DatawareHouse. Using below command

> alter database [DatabaseName] set auto_create_statistics ON
>
> Msg 104434, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 This option is not supported in
>   PDW.

I checked database version :

> Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.1091.15 Apr 4 2018 05:52:44

I tried to enable stats on another instance of Azure SQL DWH and it worked fine there. The only difference I could find is database version:

> Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.1091.36 Apr 30 2018 19:33:29

If this could be the reason then how to upgrade version for Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, upgrades to SQL Data Warehouse do not occur at the same time everywhere. Greater user control is something that the team is working on as a customer scenario. In the mean time, you can attempt a pause then resume operation and see if your instance is available for an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @hirokibutterfield. I paused and resume, it upgraded the version and now I able to enable the stats.. : )

Comment: I checked SQL DWH version on our another subscription, its showing as  - "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May  4 2018 13:05 " So how it is different than version "Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.1091.15 Apr 4 2018 05:52:44" ? If I pause and resume again older version DWH, will it get upgraded to "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) "

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) is the version you see if you are querying logical master.